# Как собрать Android Studio проект с C-кодом из-под aarch64 и без NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, android-gradle

Скажем, у меня есть Android Studio проект, который содержит как код для JVM, так и C-код, в котором я не работаю. На своем устройстве я не могу собрать этот проект в связи с отсутствием NDK под мой процессор. Точнее, он есть (https://github.com/Lzhiyong/termux-ndk/), но неофициальный и кривой.

Могу ли я как-то собрать этот код, воспользовавшись NDK на другом устройстве, который его поддерживает? Например, скомпилировать, а потом как-то вшить в проект на другом устройстве так, чтобы NDK не требовался вовсе?

UPD1.
@woesss предложил использовать подключаемые библиотеки, что не помогло - gradle-таск `extractAfatDebugNativeDebugMetadata` падает с ошибкой `No NDK installed`. Если же подключить NDK, тот, о котором я написал выше, то падает так: `org.gradle.process.internal.ExecExeption: A problem occured starting process 'command '/home/user/android-ndk-r22b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-objcopy'`
Может быть, я где-то должен указать путь? Он берет зачем-то папку `linux-x86_64`, тогда как нужна соседняя - `aarch64`

Comment: На другом устройстве собрать в библиотеку, которую подключить к проекту на целевом. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, разобрался. Вот только некий gradle task `extractAfatDebugNativeDebugMetadata` крашится с ошибкой `No installed NDK`, что-то, видимо, еще осталось, раз оно пытается что-то прочитать. Или я что-то не так понял? Я подключил *.so библиотеки, удалил папку jni и вроде как ему уже не нужен NDK. Информации о данном таске в гугле вообще нет

Comment: Я не знаю - здесь вы первопроходец ;) Если не получилось с `AAR` - попробуйте распихать непосредственно `*.so`. Здесь есть ответы по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24357687/15923106 , но довольно старые и NDK там вроде всё равно требуется, хотя не ясно зачем. На крайняк можно попробовать добавить их как ресурсы (создать папку `resources` на том же уровне, что `java` и `res`) разложив по архитектурам, так же как это создаётся при нормальной сборке. Если они попадут в APK в правильном месте, то в рантайме по любому должны подключиться

Comment: @woesss, как раз по этой инструкции делал :) всё утыкается в этот самый gradle task, он не дает собрать без NDK. У меня архитектура процессора aarch64, NDK для неё есть (https://github.com/Lzhiyong/termux-ndk/issues), но походу кривой, потому что в ошибке вот это пишется `org.gradle.process.internal.ExecExeption: A problem occured starting process 'command '/home/user/android-ndk-r22b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-objcopy'` штош... буду ждать NDK от Google

Comment: Вы таки не попробовали через `AAR`? Я подключил aar с нативным кодом к пустому проекту без подключенного NDK, сборка и запуск прошли без проблем. Основная проблема будет в том, что вам придётся вынести в библиотечный модуль весь нативный и напрямую связанный с ним java-код, чтобы из этого модуля собрать `.aar`. Для целевой машины библиотечный модуль нужно удалить и подключить вместо него готовый aar-файл. Всё это долго и нудно расписывать, но в сети можно найти примеры и разъяснения по всем шагам. Про `termux-ndk` мне показалось, что он непосредственно для андроида, а не для чистого линуха???

Comment: @woesss, хорошо, я попробую `AAR` вместо `*.so` библиотек! Да, я использую termux-ndk, это единственный вариант для меня. Но, как вы говорите, NDK мне всё равно не понадобится, если я буду использовать `AAR`. Все это нужно для того, чтобы собрать проект Telegram (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) из-под андроида (у меня установлены UserLAnd, студия, jdk и проч., шаблонные проекты успешно компилируются с нуля за 30-60 секунд, 1+9 Pro, Snapdragon 888, 12GB RAM, arm64-v8a). Ух, чую искать связанный с нативным кодом весь java-код будет сложновато, т.к. его очень много :)

Comment: В теории можно вынести только натив, но я не знаю как поведёт себя компилятор не видя связи java-методов и c++ функций. Попробуйте, может получится - возможно придётся подавить ошибки сборки через lintOptions.